# Removing conflicted javascript from page by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, email

I have problem with my 2 scripts on my web page (http://obielecki.com.pl/)

I have modernizr.custom.js to resize my image by Morphing Button Concept http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/05/12/morphing-buttons-concept.

And then i have mail sender from freelancer bootstrap template

They work just fine separated, but when i have them both i can only resize my picture.
When i try to send mail nothing is happening (no communicate).

I can't figure it out what's wrong inside this scripts, that make this kind of conflict, so i try to just remove this modernizr.custom.js after i click Send button.

I try to use jquery:

`$("<script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>").remove();`

but i can't make it to remove script after i click button, then againt put it back after user saw or click on succes mail communicate.

Comment: Try this: Move modernizr script to the head section. Leave your other script where it is. It should work, if not, let me know. Forget to mention: your code that removes the script won´t be necessary anymore.

Comment: Also check for any kind of errors on the console.

Comment: I try to move modernizr.js to head section, but it don't work. In console i see error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT . Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: In incognito in chrome i have more info about error: Uncaught ReferenceError: __xpubID is not defined.